# Run all online traffic through an PPTP VPN connection

Tags: debian, networking, ssh

I would love to run all outgoing traffic (particularly torrent and web) through an **PPTP VPN connection** (to be specific a StrongVPN.com VPN). Everything needed to setup and more important to startup the VPN connection should be done over SSH, so everything needs to be **command-line** based.

My far set goal is to create a script to achieve an auto-connected always-on VPN script.

Just to be sure: It's not about setting up a PPTP-Server on the pi (there are plenty of tutorials for that) but to connect to a PPTP-Server.

Comment: how to disconnect? I got the connection established but I don't get how to disconnect..

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To start, you will need to install pptpclient, this can be achieved by:

```
sudo apt-get install pptp-linux
```

Next, Create a file in /etc/ppp/peers with arbitrary name and the following contents:

```
pty "pptp $VPNHOSTNAME --nolaunchpppd --debug"
name $USERNAME
password $PASSWORD
remotename PPTP
require-mppe-128
require-mschap-v2
refuse-eap
refuse-pap
refuse-chap
refuse-mschap
noauth
debug
persist
maxfail 0
defaultroute
replacedefaultroute
usepeerdns
```

Where `$VPNHOSTNAME` is your VPN host name, `$PASSWORD` is your VPN password and `$USERNAME` is your VPN username.

After you have done that, you should do `sudo pon $FILENAME` where `$FILENAME` is the name of the file you saved earlier.

To start your VPN client on boot, you can follow the instructions on http://pptpclient.sourceforge.net/howto-debian.phtml (point 8 or 9, Hand configuration section)

An alternate method to make your VPN client run on boot is to make a script in `/etc/init.d` containing these contents:

```
#! /bin/sh

case "$1" in
  start)
    pon $/etc/ppp/peers/FILENAME
    echo "PPTP Started"
    ;;
  stop)
    poff $/etc/ppp/peers/FILENAME
    echo "PPTP Stopped."
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/blah {start|stop}"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

Then run:

```
update-rc.d [filename of script] defaults
```

To make it run at startup.

Comment: Awsome, you made my day. One followup question: Is there a way to check if connection has been connected inside a script?

Comment: @terman Hmm, I don't know, but from reading the docs I think not. However, I discovered a better way to run the VPN on boot, I'll link it right now.

Comment: awesome it worked for me.  Do you know how to make this work with a split tunnel?  So that only local requests are put out over the VPN and most of the web surfing is done of the regular connection.  I tried removing `defaultroute` and
`replacedefaultroute` but it didn't work.  Do you have any ideas about it?

Comment: when I run this I get the error In file /etc/ppp/peers/provider: unrecognized option '/dev/modem'

Comment: You'll need to `chmod +x [filename of script]` before running `update-rc.d`

Comment: Any idea why once I connect using sudo pon xxx, my raspbi completely shuts me down and I'm not even able to ping its IP?

Comment: If the VPN I'm connecting to has a shared secret password, where do I add it?